# second betti number of surface groups

Tags: homology-cohomology, riemann-surfaces, betti-numbers

Let $\Gamma$ be a surface group. Denote $b^i(\Gamma):=\operatorname{dim}_{\Bbb Z}H^i(\Gamma, \Bbb Z) $.

Using group cohomology for the trivial action of $\Gamma$ on $\Bbb Z$, we can see that $H^0(\Gamma, \Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z $ by taking the invariants of the trivial action.

We can see also that $H^1(\Gamma, \Bbb Z)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{Grp}(\Gamma,\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z^{\oplus 2g}  $ since $\Bbb Z$ is abelian.

How about $b^2(\Gamma)$? It is known that the Euler characteristic of a Riemann surface is $2g-2$. Does it mean that $b^2(\Gamma)=1$? can we deduce it from some kind of "integral duality" theorem that gives $b^0(\Gamma)=b^2(\Gamma)$?
Thank you.

Comment: What book on the group cohomology are you reading? If it is Brown, then you will find an answer by reading about topological interpretation of group cohomology.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to Brown's book. I was following these notes: https://kluedo.ub.rptu.de/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/5992/file/COHOM_SS18.pdf

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I think I see your point: a surface group $\pi_1 Y$ is a $K(G,1)$, so by  Proposition (4.1) page 36 in "Topological interpretation" section of Brown's book, we have $H_*(\pi_1Y)=H_*(Y)$, so in particular we can use Poincaré duality for projective surfaces, which means that homologies in degree $0$ and $2$ are the same. Is it correct?

Comment: Right. I really recommend reading Brown's book, although, as a topilogist, I am biased.

Comment: Many thanks for the nice reference, I will read it! If you put your comment in an answer, I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd cohomology group of the fundamental group of a surface $X$ of genus $\ge 1$ is isomorphic to  $H^2(X)$, hence ${\mathbb Z}$.